# A question about an irreducible polynomial in the ideal of syzygies

Tags: polynomials, finite-groups, invariant-theory, syzygies

Let $G$ be a finite group with $n$ elements and let $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]^G = \mathbb{Q}[g_1,\cdots,g_m]$, where $G$ acts through the regular representation. Then there exist polynomials $s_j \in \mathbb{Q}[y_1,\cdots,y_m]$ for $j=1,\cdots,n$ such that
$e_j(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = s_j(g_1(x_1,\cdots,x_n), \cdots, g_m(x_1,\cdots,x_n))$ for $j=1,\cdots,n$ where $e_j$ is the $j$-elementary symmetric polynomial in $x_k$. Consider the polynomial 
$p(t,y_1,\cdots,y_m) = t^n - s_1(y_1,\cdots,y_m) t^{n-1}+\cdots+(-1)^n s_n(y_1,\cdots,y_m)$ which is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[t,y_1,\cdots,y_m]$.
Let $I := \{ h \in \mathbb{Q}[y_1,\cdots,y_m] | h(g_1,\cdots,g_m) = 0\}$ be the ideal of syzygies.
Then my question is:
Can we alway choose $(a_1,\cdots,a_m) \in \mathbb{Q}^m$ such that:

1) $\forall h \in I$: $h(a_1,\cdots,a_m) = 0$

2) $p(t,a_1,\cdots,a_m)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$.

I thought of applying Hilbert's Irreducibility Theorem to get $(a_1,\cdots,a_m) \in \mathbb{Q}^m$ such that $p$ is irreducible, but how do we control that $a_j$ satisfy 1)?

Comment: I think 1) and 2) imply that $p(t,a_1,\ldots,a_m)$ has a transitive subgroup of $G$ as Galois group. So you'd be getting awfully close to solving the inverse problem of Galois theory.

Comment: If we insist that also 3) $Q_i(a_1,\cdots,a_m) \neq 0$ for arbitrary $Q_i \in \mathbb{Q}[y_1,\cdots,y_m]$, which by Hilbert's Irreducibilty Theorem can be done, than i think that the Galois group of $p$ must be $G$.